# How to restrict my particular page and it can only access after submit action occurred

Tags: php, contacts, restrict

Please help me.. I have a **contact form page** and **thank you page**. I just want to restrict my **thank you page** and it can only access after submit action on contact form click. So how can I do that? Thank you! :)

**EX:**

If directly access the **thankyou.php** ex: (localhost/test/thankyou.php). it automatic redirect on **index.php**.

And **thankyou.php** can only access after clicking the submit button or action on contact form.

Comment: Check if there is data in `$_POST`

Comment: First for contact form security, u should use google recaptcha api ( it avoids unwanted hits like bots) and also use ` $_POST ` or ajax check in php...
And for more security, use ` $_SESSION['flag'] ` :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather simple, replace $_POST with the type you are using ($_POST / $_GET)

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST)){
    header('Location:URLHERE');
    die();
}

 <<START/REST OF YOUR THANK YOU CODE/PAGE>>
?>
```

If you want to you can also check for a specific variable / name is set. Again replace the $_POST with the type you are using. ($_POST / $_GET) - Along with the variable to check for of course :)

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['name'])){
    header('Location:URLHERE');
    die();
}

 <<START/REST OF YOUR THANK YOU CODE/PAGE>>

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to have a hidden field on your form maybe called "form-sent" for example with value "yes". thrn on your thankyou page use an if statement to check this field is in $_POST along with the value:

if(isset($_POST["form-sent"]) && $_POST["form-sent"] == "yes"){

}

just a badsic example. you could in fact check it does not exist or the value is not "yes" and redirect back off the page.

sorry for poor formatting i posted on my phone.

Comment: can you tell me where I can put that php codes. sorry I'm poor on php. :)